# Issues with key values within functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dataframes and i wanted to loop through these and add a column to just put the key/name of the dataframe in to the column for reference. I can manage this outside of a function fine:

```
k = 'df1'
df_dict[k]['Source label'] = "source"
```

however if i put this inside a function like this:

```
def do_all_dfs():
    for k,v in df_dict.items():
        print(k)
        df_dict[k]['Source label'] = "source"
```

It will recognise and print the label ok, and it's type string, but it throws an error on trying to add the column:

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'source'**

I think there must be something fundamental i don't understand here, because i had a similar issue with another function where I got a NameError when using k this way - fine outside of a function, but when i put it inside one it throws an error.

There are 4 dataframes in the dictionary and all pretty much identical. As i'm just adding a column to each, i can't see what's going wrong.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use keys, instead of .items, and you do not need `v` variable in the loop

```
def do_all_dfs():
    for k in df_dict.keys():
        print(k)
        df_dict[k]['Source label'] = "source"
```

Comment: Do you think it is the `v` that cause the `keyerror`?

Comment: both, `v` and `.items`

Comment: Didn't even know I could exclude the v - in my tiny mind i thought you always had to reference both elements. Thanks! I won't dwell on why .items didn't work in this context

Comment: sadly, I am not yet very experienced in it also and I cannot explain properly, but once pandas DataFrames are stored in dictionaries,  they become dictionary of objects, and not just dictionary of values (as you would use dictionary in the normal mode).
I hope someone else, with more knowledge will takeover from this part :)